# Extension not working on open cart

Tags: php, ajax, opencart

I've installed [vqmod_admin_ajax_edit_quantity](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=5445&path=21&page=2)

Put the XML file on site.

It then tells you to  `Set $_['text_save']` and `$_['text_close']` in `admin/language/*/catalog/product.php` to customize your link Save and Close

But when I add

```
$_['text_save'] 
$_['text_close']
```

I get Syntax errors.. so I put

```
$_['text_save'] = 'Save',
$_['text_close'] = 'Close',
```

and then got syntax error, `unexpected ','`

I'm adding it here:

```
/admin/language/english/catalog.product.php
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax to use is

```
$_['text_save'] = 'Save';
$_['text_close'] = 'Close';
```